# Need to change image in current div and image in a different div on mouseover

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I am using .png image as an imported rollover image in DW. When mousing over that image I want the image to change, but I also want the content in another div to change. I am able to get one or the other to change at a time but not both. I have been using a semi-colon to separate the function calls, but to no avail.

HTML

```
<div> 
   <a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"
               onmouseover="changeIt('images/change.jpg','animationbox');MM_swapImage('Image5','',images/'peaberryrollover.png',1);">
      <img src="images/peaberrybutton.png" width="170" height="200" id="Image5" />
   </a>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeIt(imageName,objName)

    {
     var obj = document.getElementById(objName);

     var imgTag = "<img src='"+imageName+"' border='0' />";

     obj.innerHTML = imgTag;

     return;
     }


 function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: any better formated code would be appreciated

Comment: Can you clearly show which element you're changing ? Both the original image and 'the other' `div`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this page](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/javascript/changing_images_on_mouseover_mouseout_javascript.php3) where they demonstrate how they change picture on mouseover event. very simple:

```
<div>
  <a href="some.html" onmouseover="document.imageTag.src='pic2.png'"
                      onmouseout ="document.imageTag.src='pic1.png'">

    <img src="pic1.png" name="imageTag" 
         width="100" height="50" border="0" alt="..." />

  </a>
</div>
```

In this way you don't need all that javascript